# Questions regarding Libsodium

Tags: c++, libsodium

I am trying to use the lib-sodium cryptography library in Visual Studio 2015.

Following is my piece of code

```
unsigned char pk[crypto_box_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
unsigned char sk[crypto_box_SECRETKEYBYTES];

    crypto_box_keypair(pk, sk);
    cout << "\nPrivate Key: " << pk;
    cout << "\nSecret Key: " << sk;
    cout << "\n";

int m_len = 6, c_len = crypto_box_SEALBYTES + m_len;
unsigned char *m=NULL, *c=NULL;
m = (unsigned char *)sodium_malloc(m_len);
c = (unsigned char *)new unsigned char(c_len);
unsigned char *m2=NULL;
m2 = (unsigned char *) new unsigned char(m_len);

//Message to be encrpted
m[0] = 'M';
m[1] = 'C';
m[2] = '2';
m[3] = '2';
m[4] = '5';
m[5] = '\0';

cout << "\nMessage is: " << m;

if (crypto_box_seal(c, m, m_len, pk) != 0) {
    cout << "\nFail in cypto";
    return 1;
}

cout << "\nCrypted is: " << c;

if (crypto_box_seal_open(m2, c, c_len, pk, sk) != 0) {
    printf("crypto_box_seal_open() failure\n");
    return 1;
}
cout << "\nDecrypt is: " << m2;
```

Questions are as follows:

1. Every time I run the code I get different sizes of public and private key, but the size of variable I use is constant. How can this be possible?
2. I am trying to use `sodium_malloc` function to allocate memory for crypted message and decrypted message. But it throws a violation of accessing wrong memory space. Is this a problem because i am coding in C++ or is there any other reason?

Please let me know if you need any other information regarding the problem.

Comment: `cout << pk` looks wrong. I don't think you can dump an arbitrary array of bytes like that.

Comment: `new unsigned char(c_len)` looks wrong. Did you mean `new unsigned char[c_len]`?

Comment: Your second comment was indeed a mistake for me. I was trying to assign the length but instead the code was initializing it.
But still, if I replace it for sodium_malloc(), the code fails.

In the standard tests, they have coded in C, while my code is in CPP.

Comment: You'd have to show your whole code to diagnose that.

Comment: @melpomene... Please see the code...